# Unable to find empty RAM slots

Tags: linux

When I lookup the no of empty slots in Lenovo L420. I shows that I have 4 slots and two of them are empty. But I cannot find the empty RAM slots when I opened the laptop. How can I know that this command is working properly. I want to add one more 4GB memory stick in the third slot.

```
sudo lshw -C memory
```

Here is the output

```
*-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 1b
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1334 MHz (0.7 ns)
          product: RMT3020EC58E9F1333
          vendor: Fujitsu
          physical id: 0
          serial: 415A7459
          slot: DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1334MHz (0.7ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous [empty]
          physical id: 1
          slot: DIMM1
     *-bank:2
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1334 MHz (0.7 ns)
          product: RMT3020EC58E9F1333
          vendor: Fujitsu
          physical id: 2
          serial: 41733A59
          slot: DIMM2
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1334MHz (0.7ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous [empty]
          physical id: 3
          slot: DIMM3
```

Comment: Even Compuram couldn't find more than two slots : https://www.compuram.biz/memory/lenovo/notebook/thinkpad/l-series/l420/

Comment: For me, this command says there is only one slot. But in fact, there are 2 slots.

Answer (score 2):

It might be that the motherboard can support 4 DIMMs, but the OEM chose to make only two slots available and omitted the other two to save space or something. Going by [the Lenovo docs for adding RAM to the L420](https://support.lenovo.com/jp/en/solutions/migr-77451), only two are really available.

[This SU post](https://superuser.com/a/295839/334516) is informative:

> It might be showing that the chipset supports more slots, even if the
>   motherboard is not wired up to have those slots. It is more common
>   these days for the chipset to know the other sots are not present
>   (rather than just empty) but this is not always the case.
>
> ...
>
> With laptops you often find that there are two slots, one on either
>   side of the motherboard. In these cases one is usually easily
>   accessible via the under-side of the case (under a cover held in place
>   by one or two screws) and the other is on the other side of that and
>   difficult to get to (you end up having to take the laptop completely
>   apart if you want to get to it, and even then you might fins it isn't
>   a real "slot" but some memory chips soldered direct to the board).

In my own 2012's System76 Bonobo, which does have 4 slots, two are on the easily-accessible end of the motherboard (near the hard disk and battery slots), and the other two require that I practically disassemble the laptop to access it. So I'd guess that Lenovo skipped out on less-accessible ports, reducing the cost and complexity.