# How to find out how many RAM slot?

Tags: proc, lshw

I have to extend my RAM memory, Because I need to use Android Studio.
I need to find out how many RAM slot via `lshw` command or greping `/proc` contents.I don't want to open my laptop.
How can I find out?

Comment: `dmidecode` -t memory?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/425109/315749 seems to suggest that `lshw` lists all the slots, including unused ones.

Comment: `lshw -class memory` tells you firmware, cache, and memory banks in detail. IIRC, before my upgrade it reported `bank:1 unused`, and now it tells me all, including the vendor and their product code. dmidecode does much the same for main memory.